# React js components dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a question regarding what is the best structure for a react component which is composed from another components.
So the first one is :

```
<ColorSelect id="color"
label={this.state.selectLabel}
trigger={{ color: "lime", text: "Lime"}}
onPropagateClick={this.changed}>
<ColorOption color="yellow" text="Yellow" onPropagateClick={ColorSelect.optionClicked}/>
<ColorOption color="orange" text="Orange" onPropagateClick={ColorSelect.optionClicked}/>
<ColorOption color="red" text="Red" onPropagateClick={ColorSelect.optionClicked}/>
</ColorSelect>
```

here the problem is that I cannot access the ColorSelect functions from ColorOption

and second :

```
<ColorSelect id="color"
label={this.state.selectLabel}
trigger={{ color: "lime", text: "Lime"}}
onPropagateClick={this.changed}>
options={[
{ color: "yellow", text: "Yellow" },
{ color: "orange", text: "Orange" },I have a question regarding what is the best structure for a react component which is composed from another components.
```

So the first one is :

```
<ColorSelect id="color"
label={this.state.selectLabel}
trigger={{ color: "lime", text: "Lime"}}
onPropagateClick={this.changed}>
<ColorOption color="yellow" text="Yellow" onPropagateClick={ColorSelect.optionClicked}/>
<ColorOption color="orange" text="Orange" onPropagateClick={ColorSelect.optionClicked}/>
<ColorOption color="red" text="Red" onPropagateClick={ColorSelect.optionClicked}/>
</ColorSelect>
```

here the problem is that I cannot access the ColorSelect functions from ColorOption

and second :

```
<ColorSelect id="color"
label={this.state.selectLabel}
trigger={{ color: "lime", text: "Lime"}}
onPropagateClick={this.changed}>
options={[
{ color: "yellow", text: "Yellow" },
{ color: "orange", text: "Orange" },
{ color: "red", text: "Red"} />
```

In these example the component is not easy to reuse because I want to have a component where I can send the properties in json format

Comment: Please rewrite your question, explaining very clearly what you're trying to do.  The code doesn't have meaning if we don't know your goals.

Answer (score 2):

A component sees only its one props, but its parent can pass a method as a prop. This is how you may write ColorOption.

```
var ColorOption = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div style={{color: this.props.color}}
                onClick={this.props.onSelect.bind(null, this.props.text)}
                >{this.props.text}</div>
    }
})
```

Notice that when the div emits a click event, ColorOption calls its `onSelect` prop (with its `text` prop as argument). `onSelect` must be passed by the parent, and this is exactly what ColorSelect does.

```
var ColorSelect = React.createClass({
    handleSelect: function(text) {
        console.log('Color selected:', text)
    },
    render: function() {
        var options = this.props.options.map(function(option) {
            return <ColorOption key={option.color} color={option.color}
                    text={option.text} onSelect={this.handleSelect} />
        }.bind(this))
        return <div>{options}</div>
    }
})
```

ColorSelect takes an `options` prop, which must be an array, and turns it into an array of ColorOptions. Moreover, it passes its `handleSelect` method to each child, so that they can call it.

```
var options = [
    { color: "yellow", text: "Yellow" },
    { color: "orange", text: "Orange" },
    { color: "red", text: "Red"},
]
React.renderComponent(<ColorSelect options={options} />, document.body)
```

That's it.